# When it is not possible to infer the lifetime in the Rust borrow checker?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

In most cases, the Rust compiler can infer the lifetime. if the lifetime scope is determined at runtime, it says that the lifetime must be explicitly marked.

```
fn longest<'a>(x: &'a str, y: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    if x.len() > y.len() {
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}
```

Here,

- The lifetime is generic.
- This means that there is a scope bound to the lifetime 'a after the function result is returned.
- the compiler can know information that the memory is valid for the minimum lifetime 'a.

I'am very curious. instead of using a lifetime syntax, can't the compiler just adopt the fewer scope area to which lifetime 'a can be bound?

```
fn main() { //larger scope
    let s1 = String::from("long string is long");

    { //fewer scope
        let s2 = String::from("xyz");
        let result = longest(s1.as_str(), s2.as_str());
        println!("The longest string is {}", result); 
    } 
      
}
```

Even if the call stack is more complex on the caller side, the scope area is determined at the time of borrowing, so the same question seems to be possible.

```
fn func1<'a>(x: &'a str, y: &'a str) {
   let c = String::from("hello");
   let result = func2 (a,b,c)
   ...
}
```

Comment: It's great that you're learning. There's no need to apologize for it.

Comment: Rust lifetime specifiers need to be there for things like references which are always in relation to something else which has a lifetime, even if that lifetime is `static`. I'm not sure what you mean by "fewer scopes". Over time Rust seems to be getting better at inferring lifetimes, so in future versions of Rust this whole `'a` thing might just go away, but for now it's necessary. It also seems to serve to remind people that such lifetimes exist.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the answer. Added sample code for the ambiguous part of the question.

Comment: Not sure I fully comprehend what you're asking in terms of scopes vs. lifetimes.

Comment: Note that explicit lifetimes in function declarations also serve as documentation so that someone who wants to use the function will know that the result may borrow from either `x` or `y` without needing to read the code.

Comment: @tadman The compiler is indeed [getting smarter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/non-lexical-lifetimes.html) about lifetime reasoning for code that actually satisfies the lifetimes, but the compiler was insufficiently smart to understand that. As far as I know, there are no plans to infer lifetimes from function bodies, so that they'd be omitted from function signatures. That may be a valid goal for a future language offering similar borrow-checking features, but AFAIK Rust is not moving in that direction - lifetimes are here to stay.

Comment: @user4815162342 I know that they're effectively necessary due to how borrows work, but it's kind of unfortunate that Rust will never have a syntax as clean as Swift, which is a similar language that...borrows a lot from Rust, including the team!

Comment: @tadman I'm curious, how does Swift handles this case without lifetime annotations? I've done some cursory googling, but I can only find that Swift makes pervasive use of Rc.

Comment: @user4815162342 It's because everything non-trivial in Swift is intrinsically wrapped in an `Rc`/`Arc` type wrapper, so I guess it goes without saying?

Comment: Ok, I see. I guess it's one of those situations where your systems language has to choose between simplicity, efficiency, and safety, but only gets to pick two. C++  is efficient and simple (as far as lifetimes are concerned), but wildly unsafe, Swift and Go are simple and safe but not as efficient, and Rust is efficient and safe, but not as simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're approaching the question the wrong way. When compiling a function such as the `main()` you've shown, the borrow checker doesn't examine the *contents* of individual functions it calls, like `longest()`, it only examines their *signatures*. This is a feature: it allows the implementation of a function to change without affecting the guarantees provided by its signature. If `main()` successfully compiles, you can be sure that it will keep compiling however you modify `longest` as long as you don't change its declaration.

In case of `longest()`, the unannotated signature is ambiguous:

```
fn longest(x: &str, y: &str) -> &str

// does the above mean:
fn longest<'a, 'b>(x: &'a str, y: &'b str) -> &'a str // returns sub-slice of x
fn longest<'a, 'b>(x: &'a str, y: &'b str) -> &'b str // returns sub-slice of y
fn longest<'c>    (x: &'c str, y: &'c str) -> &'c str // returns sub-slice outlived by x and y
fn longest<'a, 'b>(x: &'a str, y: &'b str) -> &'static str  // returns static data
```

Without lifetime annotations we can't tell from just looking at the declaration whether the returned `&str` comes from the first `&str`, the second `&str`, a common lifetime, or possibly a static `&str`. For very simple functions, like those that accept and return a single reference, the compiler performs "[lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision)" where it mechanically picks the "obvious" interpretation of the unannotated signature, allowing you to write `fn longest(x: &str) -> &str` as a simple shorthand for `fn longest<'a>(x: &'a str) -> &'a str`. But when a function accepts multiple references, the compiler refuses to guess and makes you spell out what you wanted.

As pointed out at the beginning of the answer, and this often confuses beginners, what the compiler definitely refuses to do is infer the lifetime signatures *from the function body*, because that would make the signature dependent on the implementation.